# Signals from optical sensors to count the number of people entering/leaving a room

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

### The Problem

Suppose I have two optical sensors attached to a room's door.

When a person enters the room, these are the signals from the sensors:

[image]

When a person leaves the room, these are the signals:

[image]

Using these signals, I need to implement a counter that will tell me how many people are in the room.

*Assume up to **25 people** may be in the room at any time. Assume any other signal pattern will not happen, only one person will leave/enter at a time, and there are no other exits.*

### What I have tried

I have tried using two **74LS190**, connecting A to the clock, and B to the up/down switch. Like this:

[image]

However, I have run into some bugs when cascading: an `enter` signal when we have 9 people sends the count to 10 then to 20. This happens because of `rc`'s specification.

Comment: You will need to decode the tens enable state differently depending on the direction of the next count.  You need to count tens up when units is at 9 but count tens down when units is at 0.  The 74F269 answer below is good.

Answer (score 2):

You could pick a counter which is capable of representing the full required range natively, for example the [74F269](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74F269.pdf) which is an 8-bit counter. You can then leverage the same trick you're using to feed `B` into the clock and `A` into the up/down control. Note that this is reverse from how you're using the 74LS190 chip because the U/D pin is count up on high for the 74F269 chip (missed this before).

Answer (score 0):

This is looking like a rotary encoder modulation, 2 signals with phase moved by 90 degrees.You could try a microcontroller, is more easy to do this and some microcontrollers with small number of pins could be handy.Atmel has some of this microcontroller in package like SOIC-8, a very robust package.

Comment: I was about to mention that it was like a rotary encoder too. All I can add to your answer is that an ATTINY85 would do this job well. It has enough interrupt pins and while it is a small MCU it is up to the task.

Answer (score 0):

A D flip-flop is the simplest approach to provide a direction bit for an incremental encoder. In the diagram below, the D flip-flop is rising-edge triggered (on the CLK input). It can seen that Output A leads Output B for CW rotation, and Output A lags Output B for ACW rotation, thus, Q will be logic 1 for CW, and logic 0 for ACW.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is what's called a "quadrature decoder" and if you take a look [here](http://www.fpga4fun.com/QuadratureDecoder.html) you'll find everything you need to know.

You could also Google "quadrature decoder" for about 300 000 hits.